# gradle force version of transitive dependency not working. No exclude, override or force seems to apply

Tags: gradle, transitive-dependency, dependency-resolution

I have a conflict with a transitive dependency. Overriding, excluding or forcing does not help. What else can I do to get the right version of the library into the jar?
The full code dan be. found https://github.com/geoHeil/gradle-dependency-resolution but the main parts of it are described below.

### problem description

executing

```
./gradlew shadowJar
```

with geomesa dependencies (which pull in an outdated version of typesafe/lightbend configuration library) disabled:

```
dependencies {

    compile "com.github.kxbmap:configs_2.11:0.4.4"
    //compile "org.locationtech.geomesa:geomesa-hbase-spark-runtime_2.11:2.0.1"
}
```

and executing the jar

```
java -jar build/libs/gradleThing-all.jar
```

outputs

```
hello
my config is: Success(Job1Configuration(frequencyCounting))
```

When enabling the dependencies:

```
./gradlew shadowJar
java -jar build/libs/gradleThing-all.jar
```

it fails with

```
hello
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Failed to start. There is a problem with the configuration: Vector([extract] com.typesafe.config.Config.hasPathOrNull(Ljava/lang/String;)Z)
```

which is related to an outdated version of the config library, [how to resolve NoSuchMethodError on typesafe config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40610816/how-to-resolve-nosuchmethoderror-on-typesafe-config).
Also confirmed via:

```
gradle dependencyInsight --dependency om.typesafe:config

> Task :dependencyInsight
com.typesafe:config:1.3.1 (conflict resolution)
   variant "runtime" [
      Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
         org.gradle.usage = java-api
   ]
\--- com.github.kxbmap:configs_2.11:0.4.4
     \--- compileClasspath

com.typesafe:config:1.2.1 -> 1.3.1
   variant "runtime" [
      Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
         org.gradle.usage = java-api
   ]
+--- org.locationtech.geomesa:geomesa-convert-avro_2.11:2.0.1
|    \--- org.locationtech.geomesa:geomesa-convert-all_2.11:2.0.1
|         +--- org.locationtech.geomesa:geomesa-tools_2.11:2.0.1
|         |    \--- org.locationtech.geomesa:geomesa-hbase-spark-runtime_2.11:2.0.1
|         |         \--- compileClasspath
...
```

How can I fix the transitive dependency to my desired version of 1.3.3?

### my solutions

Trying to set:

```
compile("org.locationtech.geomesa:geomesa-hbase-spark-runtime_2.11:2.0.1") {
                exclude group: 'com.typesafe', module: 'config'
            }
```

and re running the jar fails again with the same issue.

Also an constraint https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:dependency_constraints like:

```
implementation("com.typesafe:config")
    constraints {
        implementation("com.typesafe:config:1.3.3") {
            because 'previous versions miss a method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40610816/how-to-resolve-nosuchmethoderror-on-typesafe-config'
        }
    }
```

or using force https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:enforcing_dependency_version like :

```
implementation('com.typesafe:config:1.3.3') {
        force = true
    }
```

or like:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.typesafe:config:1.3.3'
    }
}
```

does not give the right version.

### result

All variants fail with the same error

What is wrong? There must be a way to force the desired version.

Comment: Grade 4.8 RC2 does not seem to help https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5364

Comment: What does `dependencyInsight` give after excluding through `exclude group: 'com.typesafe', module: 'config'` ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/ca0d4670c1dcc13f1ed9c7429564c2a5 is returned, i.e. as expected only that dependency is visualized in the logs, however this is **NOT** the result I get in the jar, as otherwise the job would not have crashed.

Comment: Also the ideas of https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-force-a-dependency-version-while-also-substituting-a-transitive-dependency/26759/7 do not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is the exact opposite of what you are describing.

The different things you tried in your project all make sure that the version of `com.typesafe:config` is a `1.3.x`.

However, when adding `org.locationtech.geomesa:geomesa-hbase-spark-runtime_2.11:2.0.1` you pull in some dependency that already has the classes from `com.typesafe:config` but from the `1.2` line. And when you create your fat jar, that version overwrites the classes from the `1.3` line.

This can be seen by decompressing your fat jar and running:

```
$ javap com/typesafe/config/Config.class | grep hasPath
  public abstract boolean hasPath(java.lang.String);
```

showing that indeed the `hasPathOrNull` method is missing.

That shading issue is hinted at in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9441.

Given this, the easy path - if possible for you - would be to downgrade `"com.github.kxbmap:configs_2.11` to a version that relies on `com.typesafe:config:1.2.x`

The other solution is to find out exactly which fat jar is including these and see if you can exclude it from your own fat jar.

Comment: Why does not even the exclude working? Should that not exclude the dependency from the fat jar?

Comment: My intention was to get rid of the 1.2 classes

Comment: What would the process look like to find the exact jar? Should `dependencyInsight ` be the tool of choice?

Comment: Any attempt to modify the dependencies does not work because the problematic version does not appear as a dependency. The classes are already _inside_ another dependency.

Comment: Any chance to identify such a offending dependency with a tool?

Comment: You can try one of the methods described in http://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar and leverage the duplicate strategy from the Jar task, by making it fail on duplicates: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:duplicatesStrategy